# Amazon EC2 Windows: Should I have separate instances for my IIS and SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a website (ASP.Net web application) hosted on IIS on Amazon EC2 "Windows with SQL Standard" instance, where the SQL Server is on the same instance as well.

I am wondering if it would be better (strictly performance wise, i.e. would the site be faster for the user) to separate them into two instances, one for the web application on IIS, and one for SQL Server.

The application uses only Entity Framework 4 to access and read/write from the database. Workload wise, I am expecting that there will be about 1000 records (e.g. a record is a customer, each with their orders, details, history, budget, payments, etc...) getting created daily.

Server has 15GB memory, Intel Xeon CPU 2 @ 1.8Gz. Standing idle, sqlserver.exe is using 300MB memory, and the w3wp is using 600MB memory. On a single request, e.g. Login, CPU usage for sqlserver.exe goes up to 10%, and same for w3wp.exe.

I know  that there are a lot of other details that need to go into making such a decision, but I am not necessarily looking for a Yes/No answer, but hoping to get more considerations, past experiences, pros/cons, things to think about to help make a better decision, and of course recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, yes. Consensus is for a separate box for each, that said, I operate lots of low/medium traffic sites where both coexists happily on one box and there are no issues.

If money is not a problem, separate them; if budget is an issue, separate them only if you have a performance issue.

There will be a bit of extra latency with two boxes, but if you are having performance issues, then separating the servers should more than makeup for that latency loss.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should separate them and would even go as far as to consider RDS that removes many other worries. Separating the services also allows you to scale differently when you are having performance issues.